# RxSwift update several Variable(s) from one Observable

Tags: swift, struct, observable, rx-swift, frp

Structure with several Variables updated from View and from other class

```
struct MyViewViewModel  {
    let style: Variable<CustomEnum> = Variable(.value1)
    let displayedValue: Variable<String> = Variable("")
    let stepIndex = Variable(0)
    let startedDate: Date

    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

`style` - updated from 3rt part class

`stepIndex` - should update from `CocoaAction` from View and depends from `style` changing (reseting)

`displayedValue` - depends from `style` + `stepIndex` + `startedDate`

```
init(style: Observable<CustomEnum>, startedDate: Date) {
    self.startedDate = startedDate

    style
        .bind(to: self.style)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    self.style.asObservable()
        .map { _ in return 0 }
        .bind(to: stepIndex)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    self.style.asObservable()
        .map { return self.string(for: $0) } //error: Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter
        .bind(to: displayedValue)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}


mutating func string(for type: CustomEnum) -> String {
    return "\(self.stepIndex.value) + \(type) + \(self.startedDate.day)"
}
```

The main question how to process `stepIndex` variable firstly and after update `startedDate` value.

I don't want to use class instead structure I am not sure that it is so needed (to avoid retain-cycles). RxSwift should have a way to do without this.

Comment: What do you have against a class here? A RxSwift `Variable` is inherently not a value type. And why is `func string(for type: CustomEnum) -> String` mutating?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you cant. Date needs to be set at init time but step index stream emits values in an async fassion...

The only way to get this to work as i see it would be to make startDate a var Date?.